# Got duplicate key error dup key: { : undefined }

Tags: mongodb, meteor, duplicates, unique

I have an array field called `udids` in `Meteor.users` schema, which should contains unique elements. This is how I defined the index using [SimpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/simple-schema-js) and [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core):

```
new SimpleSchema({
  ...
  udids: {
    type: Array,
    index: true,
    unique: true,
    optional: true,
    sparse: true,
  },
  'udids.$': {
    type: String,
  },
  ...
})
```

However, when I start the app, I got this error: `E11000 duplicate key error collection: meteor.users index: c2_udids dup key: { : undefined }`.
I tried searching for the documents with `udids = undefined` in the database: `db.users.find({ udids: { $type: 6 } })` (`$type: 6` for `undefined` value) but it returns nothing.

Comment: [Enable profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) , check exact query that cause conflict. The error message might not be accurate.

Comment: According to your schema, udids is an array of string. Is this correct? And you want each individual udids strings to be unique, not the array itself?

Comment: @blueren This is what I want: if I have 2 users like this: `user1.udids = ['a', 'b']` and `user2.udids = ['b']`, then this should be invalid because the two users' udids have the same 'b' element.

Comment: @AlexBlex I tried set the profile level to 2 and I got the same errors (which are shown from the meteor shell)

Comment: Setting profile does not fix the problem, but gives you a chance to grab the exact query meteor sends to mongodb. Sorry if I wasn't clear about it. If you can post the raw query it will help to diagnose the problem and eventually find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a bit unclear so I had to guess the reason why. I found out that the current database already has some users with `udids = []`. I'm writing a migration script to unset this field from those users. Hopefully this will help others who have the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but it should ideally work.

1. Used `Meteor.users` as a collection name. You may want to replace it with whichever collection you want to run the validation against.
2. Made use of custom function to find at least one doc which contains the field's value in udids.
3. If you don't have access to the collection on the client side, then you can edit the custom function and have it handled [asynchronously](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#asynchronous-custom-validation-on-the-client).

---

```
new SimpleSchema({
            ...
            'udids': {
                optional: true,
                type: [String], // an array of string eg. ['A','B']
                custom: function() {

                    // this.value = current field's value
                    // Below mongo query will check to see if there is at least one 
                    // mongo doc whose udids contains the currently entered field's value.
                    // if found, then return the error message.

                    if (Meteor.users.findOne({
                            udids: {
                                $in: [this.value]
                            }
                        })) {
                        return "duplicateMsg";
                    }
                },
                ...
     });

SimpleSchema.messages({ duplicateMsg:"Udid already exists"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think this is not what I'm asking ... I still don't know what is the cause of the "dup key: { : undefined}" error